# Compiler flag in GCC (C)

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4, gcc4.7

I have read the GCC documentation and man.
If I compile the code as 
  (1) gcc -o test test.c 
I get some results when executing it.
If I compile it as
  (2) gcc -O -o test test.c 
I get different results when I run it.

Reading the GCC man, I compile using (instead of -O) all the options that the man says that the option -O active.
I do not obtain the same result as in the option (2). The result is that of the sentence (1).
What does (and not documented) change the behavior of the generated program?
The test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 0;

int main() {
    int *pntr = &var2;
    pntr--;
    (*pntr) = 99;
    printf("Var1=%d\n",var1);
    printf("Var2=%d\n",var2);
}
```

Comment: Your program is not valid because of undefined behavior - your read invalid memory and you can't do pointer arithmetic like this.

Comment: Different results probably mean your program invokes undefined behaviour.  If so, both results are right and your code is wrong.

Comment: There are a small number of optimizations enabled directly by `-O` rather than via one of the `-f` switches.

Comment: For a compiler, optimizing broken code to be worse is not forbidden.

Comment: option -O assigns in VAR2 memory before VAR1.
If I remove the -O option, the memory allocations are first VAR1, and then VAR2.
What happens is that none of the optimizers that activate the -O option (according to the gcc man) do that

Comment: = code one would expect = behavior.
For some reason the option -O acts different. Before the same code; the logic obtained is different depending on the options of the compiler

Comment: *For some reason the option -O acts different.* You broke the rules of the language by invoking undefined behavior.  Whatever happens after you invoke undefined behavior is irrelevant and meaningless.  Period.  Full stop.

Answer (score 0):

No UB no problems

```
#include <stdio.h>

union 
{
  struct
  {
    int var1;
    int var2;
  };
  int arr[2];
}u;

int main() {
    int *pntr = &u.arr[1];
    pntr--;
    (*pntr) = 99;
    printf("Var1=%d\n",u.var1);
    printf("Var2=%d\n",u.var2);
}
```